# Google Search Console(WMT) not showing clicks or CTR, how do I fix it?

Tags: google-search-console, ctr, clicks

Got an issue with WMT this month for one of the sites that we monitor. It's showing impressions and average position and there has been no decrease in organic traffic (in Analytics).

I've had a look through this forum and a few other sites and I've come to the conclusion that it is a WMT problem - but does anybody know how to fix this/work around it? Or have a better explanation for why it's broken?

Comment: We are facing same problem. Last known date is possibly 3 nov and somewhere 4 nov. I think, they are experimenting on this or some technical error To see, changes in action, we need to wait for 3-4 days.

Comment: Ours is affecting back dated data as well which isn't helpful, for us our last date of 'working data' was the end of September. We haven't changed anything on the site or in the site code either

Comment: Now, I am seeing correct date range. I think, this issue is resolved.
In case of problem continuation, you can send feedback.

Comment: Hi Vikas - we thought we had cracked it yesterday by readding the site to wmt without the www. but that doesn't appear to have fixed it. Confused now as to what it could be as everything else is reporting as normal. 

We recently had the account add some event tracking code to the site (because the contact form was hosted on a seperate domain) - do you/does anybody know if that would have had an impact?

Comment: As much i know, WMT do not require any tracking code. 

To verify domain ownership , we add some tag/ dns related changes but those are different.